# Formatting json date value

Tags: jquery, json, datetime

I am getting a json date value as `16:31:00 EDT 06-02-2014` . I need to format this to `6/3/2014 4:31 PM ET`. How can I do that?

**CODE**

```
var jsonDate ='16:31:00 EDT 06-02-2014';
var actualDate =''
```

Comment: You would need to set the value of actualDate to new Date('date value').

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Newtonsoft](http://json.codeplex.com/) for serialization, you can use its built-in formatting options:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = 
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatString = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"
    };
```

Alternatively, you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format the date as you wish in your js file:

```
moment(new Date()).format('MM/DD/YY hh:mm');
```